# Syntax error in PropertyPath 'Unmatched parenthesis' in Data Grid

Tags: wpf, caliburn.micro

I am binding my Data Table to a data grid via `ItemsSource`.
If any column name contains either a left or a right parenthesis, it's throwing some exception i.e

> An error occurred while dispatching a call to the UI Thread

am using MVVM Pattern.

**Here is the Xaml Code**

```
<DataGrid x:Name="bindedItems" Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding BindedItems}" SelectionMode="Extended"/>
```

**Here is the C# Code**

```
this.BindedItems = new DataTable();
this.BindedItems = table;
```

table columns are like this

**Right Parenthesis)**

**testing**

**Lest Parenthesis(**

and from that column skipping remaining columns.

How to handle these type of exceptions and how to skip these type of columns from UI?

Please give me any suggestion to handle these things.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: i provided small example

Answer (score 0):

Set the `AutoGenerateColumns` property to `false` and explicitly define only the columns that you want to show:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="bindedItems" Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding BindedItems}" SelectionMode="Extended" 
                  AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Id" Binding="{Binding Id}" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Or rename your columns:

```
foreach(DataColumn col in table.Columns)
{
    col.ColumnName = col.ColumnName.Replace("(", "").Replace(")", "");
}
```

Comment: different type of tables am binding i.e, every table having different type of columns. In that what should i do

Comment: Then you will have to change the column names. It makes no sense to have a single parenthesis in a column name. Anyway, these are your (only) options.

Comment: one more thing for every table having different no. of columns

Comment: if i changed every column name manually it seems to be bad coding

Comment: Nothing can be worse than having parenthesis in a column name...that's bad coding standards if any. It's so bad that it doesn't event work :)

Comment: clients can create any type of column names then we have to handle these type of things.

Comment: As already mentioned, the DataGrid does not support these kind of names.

Comment: I understood that, How can i handle that in c#. If you have any suggestion or solution

Comment: I have already given you the options in my answer. If neither of this works for you, you cannot use the DataGrid control.

Comment: if the column name will be like this i.e, "((Testing)". the above code removes all parenthesis

Comment: Yes, so why don't you remove all parenthesis? As mentioned, a column name shouldn't include parenthesis. But the code was just an example. The main point is that you need to rename the columns. If don't know how to remove any single (, you should ask a new question.